# how to create a setup.exe (windows) or package (linux)

Tags: c++, installation

I have developed a software and would like to send it to other people. 
Right now I have a folder with the compiled binary (.exe) and all necessary dlls and everything else you need.

So far I can simply copy this folder to another pc and it works.

It would be great to create a real setup.exe for windows and anything equivalent for Linux.

How can I start to create such installers? Can anybody provide a link with useful information?

Comment: You can try [WinRar Installer](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/howto/how-to-make-your-own-offline-installers-using-winrar/) or google for alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is well documented in multiple places.

To make a Windows MSI installer, take a look at [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org).

To create packages for RPM based Linux distributions, read up on [RPM](http://rpm.org). For distros using Debian (deb) packages, read [debian packages](https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages). For distributions using other package formats look at their websites and find their documentation on their package formats.

Also take a look at [flatpak](https://www.flatpak.org).